# VAST 2 overlay --- play a video when the user clicks the overlay

Tags: openx, vast

In OpenX when create video-banner user has option "When the user clicks the overlay --- Play a video "

For playing video when user clicks the overlay OpenX adds to vast the following node :

```
<Video>
    <MediaFiles>
       <MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="400" width="640" height="480" type="video/x-flv">
           <URL><![CDATA[http://videoads.openx.org.edgesuite.net/openxvideos/openx-ad.flv]]></URL>
       </MediaFile>
    </MediaFiles>
</Video>
```

OpenX uses Vast 1 for creating video banners.
The question --- how to realize the same functionality using VAST 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that in VAST 2 problem can be solved ONLY on banner level using VPAID.
See http://www.iab.net/media/file/VPAIDFINAL51109.pdf --- **6.4 Overlay Banner with c lick-to-linear video ad**